# How to access function from plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using chosen jquery plugin for my select input. I want to reset select option on click on a tag so doing so I want to access jquery plugin function. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vCE4Y/9/)

HTML

```
<select id="second" class="chzn-select" style="width:100px">
<option value="0"> select</option>
<option value="1"> mr</option>
<option value="2"> mrs</option>
</select>
<a href="#">reset</a>​
```

jquery

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen()
$('a').click(function(){
    $.chosen({results_reset})
})
```

​
function from plugin

```
Chosen.prototype.results_reset = function () {
    this.form_field.options[0].selected = true;
    this.selected_item.find("span").text(this.default_text);

    if (!this.is_multiple) this.selected_item.addClass("chzn-default");

    this.show_search_field_default();
    this.results_reset_cleanup();
    this.form_field_jq.trigger("change");

    if (this.active_field) return this.results_hide();
};
```

Here is the link for complete plugin 
http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/chosen/chosen.jquery.js

Comment: you want to reset the value of dropdown to select after reset click right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

To call a plugin function, you can do:

```
$('your-select').data('chosen').results_reset();
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vCE4Y/12/

---

You do not need to access plugin code to reset the select. You can reset it as follows:

```
$('your-select').val(0).trigger("liszt:updated");
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vCE4Y/11/

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. But can you tell me how to access plugin function for my further requirement

Comment: one more thing why we need to give .val(0)

Comment: Can we select option one on reset

Comment: Pls see my edit for calling plugin function. `val(0)` since the option with `value="0"` in your select looked like the one to select when no valid options are selected.

Comment: To select option one on reset, you can do `$('your-select').val("1").trigger("liszt:updated");`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also for resetting

```
$('a').click(function(){

     $('#second').trigger("liszt:updated");

})
```

Answer (score 0):

In Chosen Jquery

```
$('select-element').val('').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

NOTE: prior to 1.0 version used the following:

```
$('select-element').trigger("liszt:updated");
```